# FB.api 'post' returns error

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

The following code to write to a friend's wall from an app is returning an error.  How can I debug this? The user ID (VALID_USER_ID) used below is valid - I read it from a separate function. The same problem happens when I do FB.api('/me/feed', 'post'...). What am I doing wrong?

```
function postToFeed() 
{
   FB.api('/VALID_USER_ID/feed', 'post', 
   {
     message: 'Testing the Facebook JavaScript API',
     link: 'http://developers.facebook.com'
   }, 
   function(response) 
   {
     if (!response || response.error) 
     {
       console.log('Error occured');
     } 
     else 
     {
       console.log('Post ID: ' + response.id);
       console.dir(response);
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot post to a friend's wall, if you logged the error response you would see that.

Facebook has disabled posting to a friend's wall

> Post to friends wall via the API generate a high levels of negative user feedback, including “Hides” and “Mark as Spam" and so we are removing it from the API. If you want to allow people to post to their friend’s timeline from your app, you can invoke the feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag).

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/

Comment: Thanks, so what is the meaning of posting to a timeline vs wall? Is it allowed for user who has logged on to a website via FB login to post to a friend's timeline? If so how do I do that?

Comment: @user2399453 Timeline and wall are one in the same. You cannot post to a friend's wall/timeline using the API